# Changing the color of a subform's column

Tags: ms-access, format, fill

I want to change the color of a single column in a Form's SubForm. Form with subForm:

[image]

The *Default View* is Datasheet and should stay that way. For some reason I am struggling at assigning the color. If I select the whole column in *Layout view* and go to Format > Shape Fill the whole Background gets filled instead of what is intended.

[image]

I also tried changing the textBox and comboBox's fill color in the *Design view*:

[image]

Does nothing. Hope you could help me!

Comment: When form is set for Datasheet, I see only one record in Layout. Not sure what you mean by 'the whole Background gets filled' - when I switch to Datasheet, control does not show color at all. Can't set control colors this way in Datasheet form. Can set up a Continuous form to look like Datasheet.

Comment: Only the SubForm is set for Datasheet. Let me upload some screenshots so understand whats happening.

Comment: How does it matter that form is used as subform? If it is set for Datasheet, it ignores color property setting.

Comment: So, if i want the format to stay that way, assigning color to a subForm datasheet's column is not possible?

Comment: Conditional Formatting can affect color but property setting is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color property settings are ignored in Datasheet view.

However, Conditional Formatting can impact display color of textbox and combobox in Single/Continuous/Datasheet/Layout views.

Continuous view can be arranged to look like Datasheet, although Datasheet sort/filter features would not be available.